# In asterisk i want to allow only 10 digit caller ids to dial through the system

Tags: asterisk

i am using asterisk to forward calls from a softswitch to gateways, i want to allow only calls with 10 digit caller id for eg 7181234567 and NOT caller id more than 10 digits

in my extensions.conf file it has as default:

```
[globals]

[default]
exten => _X.,1,Set(CALLERID(NUM)=${FILTER(0123456789,${CALLERID(NUM)})})
exten => _X.,n,goto(a2billing-did,${EXTEN},1)
```

HOW can i allow only 10 digit caller ids through the system

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk pattern have two part, DST and SRC

This info is public avalible, not recommend you go with asterisk if you not read about patterns.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching

For your case (src exactly 10 digits) will be something like this

```
exten => _X./_XXXXXXXXXX,Something
```

or

```
exten => _X./_NXXNXXXXXX,Something
```

Comment: Hi Arheops, thanks, how do you distinguish between DST(desitination) and src(source) .  remember i want the pattern matching the source, not destination

Comment: First part of patern DST, second part of pattern - SRC. Why you just not go link i provided?

Comment: Thanks I did have a read, for those who might have the issue, what i did was:
FOR ALLOWING 11 DIGIT number and blocking bad 13 digit numbers

exten => _X./_1XXXXXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(NUM)=${FILTER(0123456789,${CALLERID(NUM)})})
exten => _X./_1XXXXXXXXXX,n,goto(a2billing-did,${EXTEN},1)

exten => _X./_XXXXXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup

Comment: Hi Arheops, even though the above helps, still some calls with 13 digits go through the system, any way i can refine the above code, or do something better to make it always block 13 digits.

Comment: Code above not allow anything except 10 digits. If you still have pass, check that you have NO other rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${CALLERID(num)})

exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($[${LEN(${CALLERID(num)})} = 10]?allow:reject)

exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n(allow),Set(CALLERID(NUM)=${FILTER(0123456789,${CALLERID(NUM)})})

exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,goto(a2billing-did,${EXTEN},1)

exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n(reject),Hangup()
```

Comment: Use the edit link just below your answer to change it instead of posting new. Or you can delete the old one if it is incorrect

Comment: No point to use LEN function if you have built-in checkup in dialplan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).